# Custom Grid Menu with 3 Pages in Flutter

Tags: menu, flutter

I need a menu like this with 3 pages and an indicator for every page in Flutter, how can I implement that? I searched in Flutter docs but I couldn't find a `widget` like this.

[image: menu with 3 pages]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/page_indicator together with `PageView`. If you need sample code, I will edit this answer after coming home

Comment: Thank you, l think its very good and  I should mix that with other Widgets to achieve my custom  menu